# Identify the same name written differently?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, duplicates, jvm

Say I have different tables with names, all differently written:

```
John Doe
John W. Doe
john doe
john w doe
```

What are you using to associate all entries to the same entity (deduplication) on the JVM?

The [Dedupe library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291199/dedupe-in-python) in Python seems a tool that would do the job. Is there something similar for the JVM, maybe using Spark?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57816223/looking-for-libraries-which-support-deduplication-on-entity) lists a few alternatives but maybe it isn't up to date.